# Datasource in Repeater in Sitecore

Tags: sitecore

I have the following inside a repeater;

```
<sc:Link runat="server" DataSource='<%# (Container.DataItem as Item).Paths.Path %>' TextField="Title" LinkField="Title" />
```

This however fails. I have also tried with

```
<sc:Link runat="server" DataSource='<%# Container.DataItem %>' TextField="Title" LinkField="Title" />
```

Which also fails. What am i missing?

Comment: Oh I also have System.Web.UI.WebContols.Repeater in <typesThatShouldNotBeExpanded>, but that probably won't make a difference here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting Item parameter instead of DataSource.  I don't have many sc:Link controls in my code, but here is one I know works:

```
<sc:Link  ID="hlMore" runat="server" Item='<%# Container.DataItem %>' Field="ImageLink" Text=<%# Sitecore.Globalization.Translate.Text("FindOutMore") %>></sc:Link>
```

Note it also uses "Field" and not TextField.  Hmmmm.  In the code behind, the data source is a List collection.

Here's another one, with a control inside it:

```
<sc:Link ID="lnkFlag" runat="server" Field="FlagLink" Item='<%# Container.DataItem %>'>
    <sc:Image runat="server" Field="FlagImage" Item='<%# Container.DataItem %>' />
</sc:Link>
```

Comment: <sc:Link  ID="hlMore" runat="server" Item='<%# Container.DataItem %>' Field="ImageLink" Text=<%# Sitecore.Globalization.Translate.Text("FindOutMore") %>></sc:Link> worked like a charm - thx! :)

Answer (score 0):

DataSource should be ID, not item or item.Path.

Item should be the datasource item.