# How to bind link items to a Repeater in Sitecore

Tags: asp.net, sitecore, sitecore8

The content tree is as follows:

```
content
 -News Listing
  -Article1
  -Article2
  -Article3
```

Each of the Articles is of a Data Template - "News Article" which is as:

```
News Article
  Article --(Field section)
    Related Articles --(Multilist - with datasource as '/content/News Listing')
```

Each article has the other 2 articles as its 'Related Articles'. For eg: Article1 has related articles 2&3 and so on.

**Markup:**

```
<h3>Related articles</h3>
<asp:Repeater ID="rpArticles" runat="server" ItemType="Sitecore.Data.Items.Item">
 <HeaderTemplate>
    <ul class="relatedArticles">
 </HeaderTemplate>
 <ItemTemplate>
    <li>
      <sc:Link Field="<%#Item.Paths.FullPath %>" runat="server" Item="<%#Container.DataItem %>">
          <sc:Text Field="Heading" runat="server"/>
      </sc:Link>         
    </li>                                
 </ItemTemplate>
 <FooterTemplate>
    </ul>
 </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

**Code:**

```
private void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   MultilistField relatedArticles = Sitecore.Context.Item.Fields["Related Articles"];
   rpArticles.DataSource = relatedArticles.TargetIDs.Select(id => Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(id));
   rpArticles.DataBind();
 }
```

The above markup is a solution from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19919954/generallink-in-sitecore)
'Heading' is the name of the field (eg: Article1, Article2 etc..)

When I browse 'News Article 1', the related articles should be 2 & 3, but the output is incorrect & also no anchor tags. Just plain text.

What is wrong in my code.

**output:**

> **Related Articles**
>   Article1
>   Article1

Comment: Have you seen https://www.google.com/search?q="sc:link"+repeater

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Datasource in Repeater in Sitecore](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11215904/datasource-in-repeater-in-sitecore)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why you changed your original question since it was almost correct. Since the item you are linking to is not specified in a General Link field you cannot use an `sc:Link` control, instead is far simpler to either use an [ASP.Net Hyperlink control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295443.aspx) which is bound from code behind in the Item_Bound event or simply append the Item URL to an anchor link:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <li>
        <a href="<%# Sitecore.Links.LinkManager.GetItemUrl((Sitecore.Data.Items.Item) Container.DataItem) %>">
            <sc:Text Field="Heading" runat="server" Item="<%#Container.DataItem %>"/>
        </a>
    </li>                                
</ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1):

My original answer was wrong as pointed out in comments. Snap response without thinking fully, sorry! Correction:

You're populating the Sitecore text field with the current context item's Header field. Instead your `sc:Text` control needs to set its `Field` property from the `Container.DataItem`.

So try replacing...

```
<sc:Text Field="Heading" runat="server"/>
```

...with...

```
<sc:Text Field="Heading" runat="server" Item="<%# Container.DataItem %>"/>
```

Comment: Field attribute expects the "Field Name" to map to, you're setting it to the text value stored in the field here. This is incorrect.

Comment: The field property is a string - not a Field object. This will not work. You need to set the Item property to the `Container.DataItem` as in the link Jan posted above.

Comment: @Qwerty You need to set the Container.DataItem on the sc:Text control. I've corrected my answer to reflect this.

Comment: @getsetcode. That partially solved my problem. Now the items are rendered correctly (Article2, Article3). But they are still text and not links.