# Bind General Link items to Repeater in Sitecore

Tags: asp.net, sitecore, sitecore8

I tried a few solutions here but none worked for me. Trying to bind link items to a repeater. I don't see any output in the rendered page. Not even the text.

**Mark Up:**

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rbBrandNav" runat="server" ItemType="Sitecore.Data.Items.Item">
  <HeaderTemplate>
   <ul>
  </HeaderTemplate>
  <ItemTemplate>
   <li>                                
     <sc:FieldRenderer FieldName="Destination URL" runat="server" />
   </li>
  </ItemTemplate>
  <FooterTemplate>
   </ul>
  </FooterTemplate>
 </asp:Repeater>
```

**C#:**

```
Sitecore.Data.Database context = Sitecore.Context.Database;
Sitecore.Data.Items.Item brandNavMenu = context.GetItem("{some-guid}");

if (brandNavMenu != null)
 {
   rbBrandNav.DataSource = brandNavMenu.GetChildren();
   rbBrandNav.DataBind();
 }
```

**Data Template:**

```
 Nav Item
   Nav Item Name - Single-Line Text
   Destination URL - General Link
```

An example Item created

```
  About Us
    Nav Item Name - About Us
    Destination URL
       Link Type - External Link
       Title - About Us Title
       Description - About Us Des
       Url - www.example.com
       Target - _blank
```

When I bind the Item.Name to the repeater, I see the items. But when binding the links, no output. In viewsource, I see the 4 `<li>` generated.

Comment: Try to add `Item` attribute to the `FieldRenderer` like that: `<sc:FieldRenderer FieldBame="Destination URL" runat="server" Item="<%# Container.DataItem %>">`

Comment: It's like it's groundhog day: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35842485/how-to-bind-link-items-to-a-repeater-in-sitecore

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add Item attribute to the FieldRenderer like that:

```
<sc:FieldRenderer FieldName="Destination URL" runat="server" Item="<%# Container.DataItem %>">
```